# What is a good place to host a community-driven examples site?

Tags: wiki, raphael

I'm a contributer to the [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com) project, and one thing we need is a central place for documentation and, IMHO, a good place for people to add examples of how to use the library to accomplish various tasks.

One of the contributers has done a great job of managing all this information himself so far, on his own personal site, but of course that means lots of maintenance for him, and makes it more difficult to make improvements, add new examples, and so on.

Is there a hosted wiki of some sort that supports allowing examples to be added? Ideally, it would allow the examples to be run; I know that there are some security questions about allowing contributed JavaScript to run, so I'd be fine with having an approval process if that's necessary, or worst case, at least an easy way to write example code and have it nicely syntax highlighted.

Anyone have a suggestion? Also, if this would be better posted to a different exchange, let me know; it's semi-programming related, but I thought it fit better here than on superuser.com.

Comment: [ **Github** ](https://github.com/) seems popular. You can host example code on there. [ **jsFiddle** ](http://jsfiddle.net/) is great to put up individual working examples that are easy to play with (it has a drop down option for Raphael now).

Comment: Yeah, but Github is clumsy, especially if you're looking for user-contributed examples/docs, and jsFiddle would be great if there was a way to organize all the fiddles into categories and tie them to Raphael...

Comment: “I'm a contributer to the Raphael project”. What sort of contributions you made? I am just curious.

Comment: Hey Dmitry! I'm on the list, so I contribute assistance when people ask, and I've submitted a patch for IE as well (https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/issues/issue/122) FYI, I was talking w/ Charles about moving some of his examples to this site if/when we can ever find a good place for it :). Thoughts welcome - you've got my email from the mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

There are places like sourceforge, Google's Code repository, and as mentioned in the comments, github.